# foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given after updating to 2.4?

Tags: magento2

After updating my shop to Magento 2.4 from 2.3 I am getting this error:

> Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given
> in
> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml
> on line 17

I checked the code in `image_with_borders.phtml on line 17` and it says:

```
foreach ($block->getCustomAttributes() as $name => $value):
```

I dumped the value of `$block->getCustomAttributes()` and its an empty string. This happens on the category page and on the homepage.

Ideas?

Comment: What is your php version ?